# How to add HTTP header to URL

Tags: api, url, curl, http-headers

I'm working with an API which provides a HTTP header called `token` with value `12abc3` and my url is https://example.com/view/quote. Is there a way by which I can add the header as a parameter in the url so that I can type it directly on my browser's address bar instead of using `cURL` or`Hurl.it`??

Comment: Can I ask why you don't want to use a tool that is designed for making HTTP requests?  Why is it important to you to be able make this request directly from the address bar?  There are ways to make this possible, but it requires creating an intermediary proxy that will create the correct HTTP request for you.

Comment: @DarrelMiller Hi Darrel I want to use excel to download the file directly thats why

Comment: // , You can pass HTTP BASIC headers with `https://maryam:maryamspass@example.com/view/quote`, according to this answer: https://serverfault.com/a/471667/282446

Answer (score 7):

The only way I can imagine being able to do this would be to write a small HTTP proxy that takes a specially formatted URL and extracts header values out of the URL and re-issues the request for you.  I'm not aware of any service to do this automatically for you.

Comment: hmm… yeah i guess so…

Answer (score -7):

I think it's too late to reply but for those who still finding the solution 
you can send your token through url like this
`https://yoururl?Authorization=Bearer yourtokenhere`

Comment: I don’t think that works for headers, only parameters?

Comment: Yes this is the way to send token but not header